# Select Features outside of polygon or reverse .filterBounds Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, filter

Is there an easy way of selecting only those features not contained inside a certain polygon, let´s call it `aoi`?

`FeatureCollection.filterBounds(aoi)` retrieves every Feature inside aoi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can invert a filter by applying .not() on the filter. Use the filter ee.Filter.bounds() to filter on a specified geometry:

```
// Load a feature collection and a area of interest
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017"),
    aoi = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[6.089352878920863, 52.37509514848742],
          [2.134274753920863, 48.106879890723306],
          [5.693845066420863, 44.90199320149313],
          [12.329587253920863, 47.63522725266723],
          [9.165524753920863, 52.24075058962476]]]);

// get only the Europian countries for this example
var Europe = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'Europe'));

// create a filter
var filterInside = ee.Filter.bounds(aoi);
var filterNot = filterInside.not();

// Map the filtered collections
Map.addLayer(Europe.filter(filterNot), {color: 'red'}, 'filter not in aoi');
Map.addLayer(Europe.filter(filterInside), {color: 'green'}, 'filter inside aoi');
```

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/da99c477d32c0e8019ea3791ed12e222)