# Select points outside of polygon in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector, differences, feature-collection

I understand how to get the points that fall **inside** a polygon with GEE:

```
// Load a feature collection and a area of interest
var dataset1 = ee.FeatureCollection("link/to/any/point/dataset/on/gee");

// Define a region roughly covering the EU.
var eu = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-26.367188,34.016242,35.332031,73.124945);
Map.addLayer(eu, {color: '000000'}, 'planar polygon');
Map.centerObject(eu);


// Filter the table geographically: only points in eu
var filtered = dataset1.filterBounds(eu);
print(filtered);
Map.addLayer(filtered, {}, 'default display');
```

How do I get all the points that are **outside** the polygon?

I've seen a topic [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312505/select-features-outside-of-polygon-or-reverse-filterbounds-google-earth-engine) that discussed how to do this with polygons, but when implementing it, I don't get a featureCollection returned, but some weird data type like:

```
Filter.not
type:Filter.not
filter:Filter.intersects
type:Filter.intersects
leftField:.geo
maxError:ErrorMargin
rightValue:Polygon, 5 vertices
```

Assistance?

Answer (score 1):

```
var filtered = dataset1.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(eu).not())
```

Comment: that seems like the right way of doing to me, but notwithstanding the fact that the points display when i do ``Map.addLayer``, i cannot print the featureCollection to the console and inspect it (error - FeatureCollection (Error)
The service is currently unavailable.) , nor can I export it (been trying to complete the export to drive for 13 hours). Which dataset does the code work for you with, if I may ask?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Momchill. I tested the code on an arbitrary feature collection of polygons. I have not encoutnered that error message before, but I get the impression that it may not be related to the code (e.g. like run time-out messages).

Comment: Are you able to share the code and tables that isn't working?